# Visual Studio c++ text editor color fail

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, colors, text-editor

For some reason, visual studio 2015 is VERY buggy when it comes to coloring. I did not have any of these issues with 2013. For example, if I type:

```
int *array = new int[100];
```

Then the "new i" will be black while "nt" is in blue. I would expect all of it to be blue or whatever colors you choose. It fixes this if I disable colorization semantics but that makes the colorization not recognize macros, parameters, and a bunch of other stuff so that isn't a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your CPU specs? At times I've seen VS highlighting be pretty resource intensive.

Comment: I find the support for C++ in Visual Studio to be pretty bad especially if you compare it with C#. IntelliSense, syntax highlighting etc. just stop working for no apparent reason. Never had such issue with C# but with C++...Well, suffice to say I gave up on VS for C++ development for good.

Comment: I don't think it's my cpu causing issues. It updates immediately. But @rbaleksandar comment above means I likely won't find a solution. And it's true too. I mean visual C++ literally just keeps getting worse. And the C support is a joke. I mean they don't even fully support C99. Like really Microsoft???